# How to correct typos in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like that

```
    a      b    c
1   "hi"   1    2
2   "hi"   4    1
3   "Hi"   1    3
4   "hi"   2    1
5   "Hi"   2    1
```

all "Hi" should be corrected to "hi", how could I precede this cleanly with pandas

this is a toy example, real data can be larger

Comment: Do you have more than just the Hi->hi scenario?  e.g. Bye->bye, Hello->hello, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be lowercased, you can do -

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.lower()
```

If you want to replace certain words -

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace('Hi', 'hi')
```

Or if the word appears in a phrase, use regex -

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace('\bHi\b', 'hi')
```

This regex option allows you to work even with words -

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
             a  b
0           hi  1
1           hi  2
2       Hi mom  3
3  mom Hi, mom  4
4      mHim Hi  5

In [13]: df['a'] = df.a.str.replace(r'\bHi\b', 'hi')

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
             a  b
0           hi  1
1           hi  2
2       hi mom  3
3  mom hi, mom  4
4      mHim hi  5
```

Note that all words 'Hi' got replaced with 'hi', but in the last example, where 'Hi' appeared in the middle of a word, the replacement was not done.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`:

```
In [127]: df.loc[:, "a"] = df.a.replace("Hi", "hi")

In [128]: df
Out[128]:
    a  b  c
1  hi  1  2
2  hi  4  1
3  hi  1  3
4  hi  2  1
5  hi  2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a lambda function to the column `a` in your dataframe that returns the lowercase of the string contained, if your correction is just making the string lowercase.

e.g.

```
df.a = df.a.apply(lambda x: x.lower())
```

the `apply function` method can be extended for other more specific replacements.

e.g.

```
df.a = df.a.apply(lambda x: 'hi' if x == 'Hi' else x)
```

Or you can use a function instead of a lambda for more complicated transformations.

```
def my_replacement_func(x): 
    return x.lower()
df.a = df.a.apply(my_replacement_func)
```